# Getting SSL and connection error with java function app in azure

Tags: mysql, azure, ssl, jdbc

I tried to deploy a Java and Maven function app to Microsoft Azure. The deployment goes well but when I try to run the program it gets all these errors. I start getting all these communication errors. Everything works locally but when published it doesn't. I don't know what info I should give here. But if someone has got the same problem it would be appreciated if someone could help. I can provide more info if asked but don't know what I should put here.

```
> Result: Failure
Exception: KeyException: Key does not exist.

Stack: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodInvokeInfo.invoke(JavaMethodInvokeInfo.java:22)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodExecutor.execute(JavaMethodExecutor.java:54)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:51)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:92)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.beginTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:409)
    at io.madtrix.producerutil.dao.TokenRepository.getMadtrixTokenForManagerAccountAuthenticatedSourceWithClientId(TokenRepository.java:139)
    at io.madtrix.MessageHandler.<init>(MessageHandler.java:38)
    at io.madtrix.TwitterProducer.run(TwitterProducer.java:31)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:692)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1469)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:108)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:87)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:71)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:932)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:857)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:444)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:226)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor36.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:59)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:103)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:149)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:165)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:355)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:789)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:499)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:217)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1411)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:165)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:876)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.KeyException: Key does not exist.

    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1964)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1921)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1904)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:213)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:206)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:350)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.KeyException: Key does not exist.

    at sun.security.mscapi.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:310)
    at sun.security.mscapi.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:334)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
    at java.security.Signature$CipherAdapter.engineVerify(Signature.java:1319)
    at java.security.SignatureSpi.engineVerify(SignatureSpi.java:278)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1228)
    at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:704)
    at sun.security.ssl.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:182)
    at sun.security.ssl.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:175)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1222)
    at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:655)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ECDH_ServerKeyExchange.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:1118)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:284)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyException: Key does not exist.

    at sun.security.mscapi.RSACipher.encryptDecrypt(Native Method)
    at sun.security.mscapi.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:294)
    ... 41 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the connection to MySQL. It used SSL=true but when changed to SSL=false it started working normally.